# Laravel Storage rename file before downlaod

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I want to rename a file in the moment before download it in Laravel 8.0:

I currently using the following code:

```
$link = Storage::cloud()->download($request->input('document'));
```

But I can't find a way to rename it before download it. I don't want to rename the file in S3.

Comment: $link = Storage::cloud()->download($request->input('document'),"newfielname.jpg"); pass second argument  to download method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass second argument to download method as below

```
$link = Storage::cloud()->download($request->input('document'),"newfilename.extension");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as below:
Second parameter is return file name
Third parameter add header info to your file

```
return response()->download(storage_path($path), 'new name.extension', array('content-description'=> 'description'));
```